# game freezes while checking built in dictionary Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, sprite-kit

I am making a simple word game based mostly in SpriteKit.
There is a simple array of 6 letters.
When a letter is grabbed in my Spritekit game and is added to the array a simple bit of code checks to see if the array is now a legitimate word..

```
   let joined = wordArray.joined()
            print(joined)
            if UIReferenceLibraryViewController.dictionaryHasDefinition(forTerm: joined) {
                print("THATS A WORD")
                AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(systemSoundFanfare)
            }
```

this bit of code is in my `func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact)` function

My problem is the whole game freezes when it does this check for 0.5 seconds or so. Presumably because it is iterating though the entire dictionary each time!
How can I get around this so the Spritekit scene is not interrupted while this check happens?

Answer (score 0):

Use a set to hold the words. Swift sets and `NSSet` have a `contains` function where you supply a string and returns whether the string is in the set. Because each element in a set is unique, finding an item in a set is faster than finding an item in an array.

I used the following function in a word game to quickly check if a string is a word

```
// words is a set containing the words
func isAWord(_ word: String) -> Bool {
    // The words set contains the empty string, but it's not a word.
    if word.isEmpty {
        return false
    }
    return words.contains(word)
}
```

Comment: but I'm using the iOS built in dictionary to check the word is legitimate. I'd need the whole contents of the dictionary in a set??

Comment: I have not used iOS's dictionary, but I doubt it was meant to be used as often as a word game looks up words. If you want speed, use a set. I don't know how to load the built-in dictionary into a set. But you can find a downloadable word list online, such as [English word list](https://www.wordgamedictionary.com/english-word-list/), download it, add the word list to your project, and write a function that loads the word list from the app bundle into a set.